# How to get SIM1 or SIM2 from call logs programatically

Tags: android, android-phone-call

In my application I need to display call log as sim1 or sim2.
I am able to get number, name,incoming or outgoing and time stamp, but I'm unable to retrieve which sim card slot is used.

I'm using the following code:

```
  Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
  String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

  Cursor cursor_call_logs = getContentResolver().query(callUri, null,null, null,strOrder);

  while (cursor_call_logs.moveToNext()) {
     String num = cursor_call_logs.getString(cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
     String name = cursor_call_logs.getString(cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
     String duration = cursor_call_logs.getString(cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
     int type = Integer.parseInt(cursor_call_logs.getString(cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
     String callDate = cursor_call_logs.getString(cursor_call_logs
                                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));

    Log.e("VIA_NUMBER", "val@@ " + cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex("VIA_NUMBER"));
    Log.e("normalized_number", "val@@ " + cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndex("normalized_number"));
    Log.e("subscription_id", "val@@ " + cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subscription_id"));
```

How can I retrieve which sim card slot was used for the phone call.

Comment: you may determine with **cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subscription_id")** which you gives integers. that depends on SIM1 or SIM2

Comment: subscription_id: val@@ 289918191611908800998
subscription_id: val@@ 289918191611908800998
subscription_id: val@@ 289918191611908800998
subscription_id: val@@ 189918540100001021460
subscription_id: val@@ 189918540100001021460
subscription_id: val@@ 189918540100001021460, yes sim 1 for first 3 sim2 for second 3

Comment: but how to categorize, which one is sim1 and which one is sim2

Comment: **subscription_id** varies on devices so if you are using this code for specific only one device then you manually set like     if ( cursor_call_logs.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subscription_id").isEquals("289918191611908800998"){String sim = "SIM1";}else {String sim = "SIM2";}

Comment: in one device it is ok, but other devices it will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161179/discussion-between-rams-and-omi).